# How do I adjust my XSLT script to replace Q# with Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.?

Tags: xslt

I need to setup an XSLT script to replace all instances of Q# in the below HTML with Q1, Q2, Q3, etc. My knowledge of XSLT is extremely limited so I'm not sure where to start.

```
<li property="ktp:stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" class="ktp-stimulus">
        <section property="ktp:passage" class="ktp-passage">
               <p class="text-center">[1] </p>
               <p>Susan La Flesche Picotte, the youngest daughter of Joseph La Flesche, the last traditional chief of the Omaha tribe, was born in Nebraska in 1865. While her siblings became authors, orators, and <strong>Q#</strong> <u>anthropologists.</u> Picotte distinguished herself by becoming the first American Indian woman to earn a medical degree. </p>
               <p class="text-center">[3] </p>
               <p>While working at the mission school, Picotte <strong>Q#</strong> <u>befriended</u> Alice Fletcher, another teacher. When Fletcher became seriously ill, Picotte tended to her. <strong>Q#</strong> <u>On more than one occasion,</u> Fletcher encouraged the younger woman to obtain a college degree in the health professions.</p>
</section>
                    </li>
```

This is where I've started with the portion of my script to make the change but I don't know when to go from here.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:li[@property='ktp:stimulus']">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
```

How do I tell it to look for any instances of Q# and then how do I replace it with Q1 and increase by 1 for each subsequent instance?

Comment: are they always in the `strong` element, or are you looking for that text anywhere within the document?

Comment: Yes, they'll always be within the strong element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a specific template matching the `strong/text()` that have the value "Q#" and then use [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-number) to generate the incrementing numbers:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="strong/text()[.='Q#']">
        <xsl:text>Q</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number count="strong/text()[.='Q#']" level="any" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the following output:

```
<li property="ktp:stimulus" typeof="ktp:Stimulus" class="ktp-stimulus">
    <section property="ktp:passage" class="ktp-passage">
        <p class="text-center">[1] </p>
        <p>Susan La Flesche Picotte, the youngest daughter of Joseph La Flesche, the last traditional chief of the Omaha tribe, was born in Nebraska in 1865. While her siblings became authors, orators, and <strong>Q1</strong> <u>anthropologists.</u> Picotte distinguished herself by becoming the first American Indian woman to earn a medical degree. </p>
        <p class="text-center">[3] </p>
        <p>While working at the mission school, Picotte <strong>Q2</strong> <u>befriended</u> Alice Fletcher, another teacher. When Fletcher became seriously ill, Picotte tended to her. <strong>Q3</strong> <u>On more than one occasion,</u> Fletcher encouraged the younger woman to obtain a college degree in the health professions.</p>
    </section>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's not running when I run it on the full HTML file. When my top HTML row contains ```<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" designation="" enumeration="">``` it doesn't work but when I adjust it to just ```html``` it runs as expected. What would be causing that?

Comment: The HTML namespace. Add a namespace declaration in the top of the stylesheet with a prefix I.e. xmlns:html=“http://www.w3 .org/1999/xhtml” and then adjust the XPath references to use that prefix i.e. html:strong/text()

Comment: Your input is in a namespace so you need to reference that namespace in your XSLT.